# DNS resolve .com domain on local domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm building a local 2008 R2 domain as a test case to be able to write a roadmap for the real new domain that needs to be created soon.

What I would like to know if I'm able to make a record in DNS that will point the domain name:
www.example.com and example.com to one of the servers in my network.

I tried creating an a-record for it but that doesn't work. To be honest I'm not even sure if this is possible?

So can I do this? That way I would be able to fully test all our services (and webb app) offline before I build the real domain and switch the DNS records at the provider.

Some advice if possible and where to start is appreciated.

The solution (Thanks Brent):

- Create new Forward lookup zone pointing to example.com
- Create empty A record pointing to IP of the webserver you are targeting
- If www is needed create A record with Name: www and IP of your webserver
- sub domains repeat the process but then with names for example: sub or
  www.sub (and ip your webserver)
- Be aware of the DNS Cache while you are in this process. Things can take time or do the following:

  - Right click the server and choose clear cache
  - in CMD: ipconfig /flushdns (to flush the client cache)

Comment: Just a note that running ipconfig/flushdns on the DNS server flushes the DNS client cache, not the DNS server cache.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new forward lookup zone in your DNS box that matches the domain name you are trying to redirect.

We did this for ADFS to resolve fs.mydomain.com to a local IP.

So create a new forward lookup zone and then setup whatever A records you want it to resolve.

Comment: Hi Brent, Ok sounds good I will try this now. Will report back in a sec.

Comment: Ok I've added the Forward lookup zone for the main domain. But now this lookup zone is pointing to the machine the DNS server is running on. What should I change in this zone to make this zone resolve to the network IP I want? Thanks

Comment: create an empty A record... so in Windows it looks something like .yourdomain.com -> IP 123.123.123.123

Comment: Ok I've created a new A record. Name I left blank so it resolves to parent and IP is the machine I'm targeting.
But when I do a cmd: tracert mydomain.com I get: "unable to resolve target system name mydomain.com" 
I have a feeling we are getting close but I'm doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: What does an nslookup to that record say?

Comment: server: unknow
ip: ::1
name: mydomain.com ip: the correct ip.
So it looks better strange that tracert doesn't give any it does give the normal domain.
Let me check if I can browse the website or not

Comment: Ok looks good we are making good progress thanks!
Now I'm able to browse my website as in: 'domain.com'
now the can we also get 'www.mydomain.com'. (with www)
I tried adding A record with name www but that doesn't seam to work. O yeah and that unknown server for NSLOOKUP is this a problem or not? (When I ns the real domain (online) I do get a server and IP?)

Comment: mmm for a test I also created sub domain like test.mydomain.com works out fine too... only the www thingie not flying

Comment: It is probably not returning the server name because reverse lookups are not setup, just a thought.

Comment: As for the www record, creating an A record for www.yourdomain.com should do it, not sure why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Brent thanks for helping me out! I created A record in the zone with name www and IP the webserver I'm targeting. Like I said everything without the www flies... Just to be sure I'm going to recreate that record now

Comment: OK, worst comes to worse it may help if you can send a screenshot of your DNS window, may be something else that is causing a problem... feel free to redact IPs as needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3686/discussion-between-joost-verdaasdonk-and-brent-pabst)

Comment: Server unknown when running nslookup means there's no reverse lookup zone matching the ip address/subnet of the DNS server. It's totally harmless and irrelevant, so no worries with that.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks turned out to be the DNS Cache Brent helped me out in the Chatroom. I'll put a summary in my original question to have the solution in a smaller size text!